# Apply a function to a linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_link(s):

    return s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))

def link(first, rest):

    assert is_link(rest)
    return [first, rest]

def first(s):

    assert is_link(s)
    assert s != empty
    return s[0]

def rest(s):

    assert is_link(s)
    assert s != empty
    return s[1]
```

I want to create a function

```
def map_link(lst, f):

"""Maps f onto each element in the linked list.

    >>> r = link(1, link(2, link(3, empty)))
    >>> map_link(r, lambda x: x**2)
    [1, [4, [9]]]
    >>> r = link(1, link(2, link(3, empty)))
    >>> map_link(r, lambda x: x + 2)
    [3, [4, [5]]]
    >>> r = link(1, link(2, link(3, empty)))
    >>> map_link(r, lambda x: -x)
    [-1, [-2, [-3]]]
    >>> r = empty
    >>> map_link(r, lambda x: -x)
    []
    """
    if lst == empty:
        return []
    else:
        return link(f(first(lst)), link(map_link(rest(lst), f), empty))
```

My outputs are like this:

```
[1, [[4, [[9, [[], 'empty']], 'empty']], 'empty']]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please explain the output you want.

Comment: It appears that you already have the logic well in hand.  I don't see where you're stuck.  What's the problem with a direct implementation of your code?

Answer (score 2):

All those `is_link` and `assert`s do not belong there at all, this completely & catastrophically breaks the asymptotic behavior of all operations.

If you cut out all the irrelevant `assert`s, you obtain something like this:

```
def link(first, rest):
  return [first, rest]

def first(s):
  return s[0]

def rest(s):
  return s[1]
```

I don't know what `empty` was, so in the following, I replaced it by `None`.
Now you can define the `map_link` as follows:

```
def map_link(lst, f):
  if lst is None:
    return None
  else:
    return link(f(first(lst)), map_link(rest(lst), f))
```

Example. Squaring all entries in the linked list with entries `1, 2, 3`:

```
print(map_link(link(1, link(2, link(3, None))), lambda x: x * x))
```

outputs:

```
[1, [4, [9, None]]]
```

---

Your original code should be reparable in the same way (untested, because I don't know what `empty` is supposed to be):

```
def map_link(lst, f):
    if lst == empty:
        return empty
    else:
        return link(f(first(lst)), map_link(rest(lst), f))
```

Comment: I have to include the assert and is_link inside of these function. So the second argument of function link must also be a link function. eg. r = link(1, link(2, link(3, empty)))

Comment: btw empty = 'empty'

Comment: @ChengmingGu As I said, while you can include those asserts, they quite frankly make no sense whatsoever, because thanks to `assert is_link` both `first` and `rest` become `O(n)`, which makes the list not only practically useless, but also theoretically useless... However... Does it work, or did you want to have something clarified?

Answer (score 0):

A brand new approach would be to implement a new `LinkedList` class which will support the use of `map`.

This only requires that we implement the `__iter__` special method, but here is an example which also implements `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

```
class LinkedList:
    Empty = object()

    def __init__(self, lst=None):
        lst = list(lst or [])
        if lst:
            self.v = lst.pop(0)
            self.tl = LinkedList(lst)
        else:
            self.v = self.Empty
            self.tl = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self
        while node.v is not node.Empty:
            yield node.v
            node = node.tl

    def __len__(self):
        if self.v is not self.Empty:
            return 1 + len(self.tl)
        else:
            return 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if self.v is self.Empty:
            raise IndexError

        if item < 0:
            item = item % len(self)

        if item > 0:
            return self.tl[item - 1]

        return self.v
```

You can now use `map`.

```
def add_one(item):
    return item + 1

ll = LinkedList([1, 2, 3]) # [1, 2, 3]

mapped_ll = LinkedList(map(add_one, ll)) # [2, 3, 4]
```

You can then proceed to implement more special methods such as `__setitem__` and other list methods such as `insert` to have a linked list implementation that uses the same API as `lst`.